# Cant dismiss notification - setActive does not work

Tags: audio-service

I cant dismiss ongoing notification. It cant be dismissed programmatically - it always stays visible. User can swipe it away.

Implementation is same as here:
[implementation example](https://github.com/azamor-luccas/audio_service/blob/minor/audio_service/example/lib/example_video_player.dart)

I want it to dismiss when the user closes this screen.

This does not work:

```
final session = await AudioSession.instance;
await session.setActive(false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dismiss audio_service's notification, you need to use methods of the audio_service package, not methods of the audio_session package. From the documentation of [BaseAudioHandler.stop()](https://pub.dev/documentation/audio_service/latest/audio_service/BaseAudioHandler/stop.html):

> Stop playback and release resources.
>
> The default implementation (which may be overridden) updates
> playbackState by setting the processing state to
> AudioProcessingState.idle which disables the system notification.

So to dismiss the notification programmatically, you can call this method.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed by adding super.stop(); to overriden stop method. Thanks !

Comment: You're adding another answer, but not marking the first answer as accepted.